# Разные результаты запросов из временной таблицы Oracle в пределах моей сессии. Почему?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Работаю с Oracle Apex, планирую использовать временную таблицу для сохранения лога загрузки файлов. Вроде бы все просто: при сабмите страницы делаю обработку загружаемого файла и после ее завершения (успешного/неуспешного) кладу в лог-таблицу отчет о результате загрузки.

Т.е. пользователь системы, который загружает файлы, по идее должен видеть, какие он файлы загружал, успешно ли файл обработался и т.д. Но после загрузки страница обновляется и таблица лога пустая, хотя запись была добавлена в лог-таблицу. Если ее несколько раз попробовать пообновлять, то можно увидеть строки лога, но это 50 на 50: то строки отображаются, то нет.

Временная таблица создана как `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, т.е. данные хранятся до завершения сеанса, но при селекте из этой таблицы я то вижу логи своих загрузок, то вообще пустая выборка получается.

Не понимаю, почему такая ситуация возникает? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать и исправить, чтобы пользователь всегда видел лог своих загрузок в пределах текущей сессии.

---

UPD: Такое ощущение, что записи добавляются рандомно в несколько разных инстансов этой таблицы и так же потом рандомно выбираются, на какой инстанс попадет.

Comment: судя по описанию у вас меняется `DB session` - если работать в одной сессии такого быть не должно. В качестве проверки выведите на печать [ID  сессии](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_to_display_session_id_sid.htm)

Comment: @MaxU, Но этот параметр вообще при каждом запросе разный получается: `select sys_context('USERENV','SID') from dual;` Если выполнить этот запрос в SQL Workshop'е   5 раз, то каждый раз будет новое значение

Comment: У меня даже была мысль сохранять в лог-таблице этот идентификатор (ID сессии), и по нему уже выбирать нужные записи для конкретного пользователя, но он при каждом запросе новый выводится. Может это у Apex'а такая особенность?

Comment: Ну если SID меняется, то и сессия постоянно новая, то есть, с временной таблицей вы не сможете сохранить логи.

Comment: Спасибо за отклики! Тогда буду делать по-другому сохранение логов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для одной APEX сессии при обработке запроса страниц создаются или переиспользуются сессии БД из пула соединений.

Таким образом, временные таблицы не могут быть использованы для хранения значений, которые должны быть доступны в рамках одной APEX сессии, так как их записи доступны только для сессии БД их создавшей.

Для сохранения значений при смене или обновлении страниц следует использовать состоние APEX сессии (см. гл. [Managing Session State Values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmdb/managing-session-state-values.html#GUID-EF798946-9E8A-430E-94F5-C2AF6EABE264)).